# How to send data between one application to other application in android?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, intentfilter

i've tried to sending  data between **App1** to **App2** via Intent in Android

i used this code but i couldn't resolve my problem.

App1 MainActivity :

```
        Intent i2 = new Intent("com.appstore.MainActivity");
        i2.setPackage("com.appstore");//the destination packageName
        i2.putExtra("Id", "100");
        startActivity(i2);
```

App2 MainActivity :

```
Bundle data = getIntent().getExtras;
if(data!=null){
    String myString = b.getString("Id");

}
```

Manfiest App2 MainActivity:

```
   <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND_MULTIPLE" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>
```

Comment: Make use of [Content Providers](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html) for sending data between application.

Comment: @Arshak content provider is probably overkill to send a `String` from one `Activity` to another.

Answer (score 8):

Final code:

**App 1 :**

```
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setClassName("com.appstore", "com.appstore.MyBroadcastReceiver");
        intent.setAction("com.appstore.MyBroadcastReceiver");
        intent.putExtra("KeyName","code1id");
        sendBroadcast(intent);
```

App 2:

```
Reciver:
public class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Data Received from External App", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
}
```

Manifest :

```
        <receiver
            android:name=".MyBroadcastReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="first_app_packagename" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

MainActivity :

```
  MyBroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new MyBroadcastReceiver();
        registerReceiver(mReceiver,
                new IntentFilter("first_app_packagename"));
```

Comment: This may work for you, but you have way too much stuff in here and you probably don't understand why your code works. First of all, if you have an `<intent-filter>` declared in the manifest, you do not need to specify `exported="true"` because that is the default, you do not need to specify `enabled="true"` because by default all components are enabled. Secondly, if you specify an `<intent-filter>` in the manifest, you do not need to register the `BroadcastReceiver` by calling `registerReceiver()`. You do **either the one or the other, not both**.

Comment: Thirdly, both your `<intent-filter>` declaration in the manifest and your use of `IntentFilter` in `registerReceiver()` are useless, because you never actually send a broadcast `Intent` that contains the ACTION "first_app_packagename". Fourthly, since you explicitly set the COMPONENT on the broadcast `Intent` using `setClassName()`, you do not need to set the ACTION in the broadcast `Intent`. That is also useless.

Answer (score 4):

My requirement was to send the **"user id" from App1 to App2** and get **"username" back to App1**.

I needed to **launch my app directly** without any chooser. I was able to achieve this using **implicit intent** and  **startActivityForResult**.

App1 > MainActivity.java

```
private void launchOtherApp() {
    Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
    //Need to register your intent filter in App2 in manifest file with same action.
    sendIntent.setAction("com.example.sender.login"); // <packagename.login>
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("user_id", "1111");
    sendIntent.putExtra("data", bundle);
    sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
    if (sendIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        startActivityForResult(sendIntent, REQUEST_CODE);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE) {
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            Bundle bundle = data.getBundleExtra("data");
            String username = bundle.getString("user_name");
            result.success(username);
        }
    } else {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
```

I had two activity in App2 ie. MainActivity and LoginActivity.

App2 > AndroidManifest.xml

```
<activity android:name=".LoginActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <!--The action has to be same as App1-->
        <action android:name="com.example.sender.login" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Sorry for this I had a little mix up with Java and Kotlin. My second app was in Kotlin, not that it will effect in any way.

App2 > LoginActivity.java

```
override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()
    var userId = "No data received"
    val intent = intent
    if (intent != null
        && intent.action != null
        && intent.action.equals("com.example.sender.login")
    ) {
        val bundle = intent.getBundleExtra("data")
        if (bundle != null) {
            userId = bundle.getString("user_id")
            userId = " User id is $userId"
        }
    }
    tvMessage.text = "Data Received: $userId"
}

fun onClickBack(view: View) {
    val intent = intent
    val bundle = Bundle()
    bundle.putString("sesion_id", "2222")
    intent.putExtra("data", bundle)
    setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent)
    finish()
}
```

Answer (score 3):

When you do this:

```
    Intent i2 = new Intent("com.appstore.MainActivity");
    i2.setPackage("com.appstore");//the destination packageName
    i2.putExtra("Id", "100");
    startActivity(i2);
```

you are calling the single-argument constructor of `Intent`. In this constructor, the argument is interpreted as the `Intent` ACTION. You then set the package name in the `Intent`.

When you call `startActivity()` with this `Intent`, Android will look for an `Activity` that contains an `<intent-filter>` with the specified ACTION. There are no installed applications that have an `Activity` defined like this in the manifest:

```
<activity>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.appstore.MainActivity"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

So Android will not be able to find and launch the `Activity` that you want.

As you want to specify explicitly the component that you want to use, instead of using the 1-argument `Intent` constructor, you should do this instead:

```
    Intent i2 = new Intent();
    i2.setClassName("com.appstore", "com.appstore.MainActivity");
    i2.putExtra("Id", "100");
    startActivity(i2);
```

Using `setClassName()` you provide the package name and the class name of the component that you want to launch.

Comment: your code run other application and don't send data

Comment: You need to explain what you mean by "send data". What data do you want to send?

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

*APP1*

```
    Intent i2 = new Intent();
    i2.setComponent(new ComponentName(PACKAGE,ACTIVITY));//the destination packageName
    i2.putExtra("Id", "100");
    startActivity(i2);
```

*APP2*

```
    String myString = getIntent().getStringExtra("Id");
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `Bundle.putSerializable(Key,Object);` and `Bundle.putParcelable(Key, Object);` 
the former object must implement `Serializable`, and the latter object must implement `Parcelable`.

Comment: how to put bundle Bundle.putSerializable(Key,Object); inside intent?

Comment: Because `String` has implemented `Serializable`, `i2.putExtra("Id", "100");` is ok. But, to start a explicit Activity, use `i2.setClassName("com.appstore" "com.appstore.MainActivity");  instead.

Answer (score 0):

***Content providers:***

Content providers are the standard interface that connects data in one process with code running in another process.

[See Android Docs.](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html)

Content provider working demo [**here.**](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_content_providers.htm)

Comment: i find this example.  http://infobloggall.com/2015/04/14/communication-between-two-applications-in-android-using-messenger/