# Android: Is there any way to stream images from one Android application to another?

Tags: android, service, video-streaming, streaming, android-service-binding

I want to stream images from one video-capture Android application to another Android application in real time on the same phone. The former video application records and processes images. I would like to stream these images as they are created directly into the second Android application. I have control over the implementation of both applications and can make the video-capture Android app run as a service.

I have found a lot of support online around how to send video or images between applications [via Intents](https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/send#send-binary-content) or [broadcasts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38608496/how-to-send-data-between-one-application-to-other-application-in-android). However these methods aren't done in real time and require the full video file. Any direction at all would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The Android SDK does not have much for this scenario. It's rather specialized and would have performance issues on older/weaker devices. Plus, I would expect most video-processing scenarios to be just in a single app, not split across two.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a content provider (in the video-capture app) that allows other apps to open the content as an InputStream. The other app will read that InputStream. This should work more or less in real-time.